# HP OfficeJet 6500A not responding from OSX

Tags: macos, printing

I can't connect to my HP OfficeJet 6500A from my MackBook Pro anymore, but it used to work. "Printer is not responding". Accessing the printer web page also fails.

The printer works if accessed from Win10 and Ubuntu 16.04LTS, both using wired connection though and having a static IP.

The MBP is on wireless. Sometimes, I manage to print from it if wired, but it typically won't connect after a second or a third attempt or so. Restarting the printer seems to help. Sometimes. Very weird.

I've disabled the built-in OSX firewall for testing purpose.

```
youri:Temp $ ifconfig | grep netmask
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
    inet 192.168.1.71 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255    

youri:Temp $ curl -i -vvv 192.168.1.6
* Rebuilt URL to: 192.168.1.6/
*   Trying 192.168.1.6...
* connect to 192.168.1.6 port 80 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 192.168.1.6 port 80: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.1.6 port 80: Connection refused
```

But `ping` responds:

```
youri:Temp $ ping 192.168.1.6
PING 192.168.1.6 (192.168.1.6): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.6: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=1.389 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.6: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.535 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.6: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.359 ms
--- 192.168.1.6 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 1.359/1.428/1.535/0.077 ms
```

Printer:

- fixed IP 192.168.1.6
- subnet mask 255.255.255.0
- Bonjour, SLP, WS Discovery and WS Print enabled
- IPP disabled

Printer installed twice, using the HP driver and letting OSX install it (so two entries in "Printers & Scanners").

OSX 10.11.6

I'm running out of ideas to further troubleshoot. Something blocking the IP/port, on the Mac or on the printer? Any clue? Thanks.

Comment: Have you restarted the network router in your configuration?

Comment: Yes, several times. Wifi AP too. Turn off & on everything.

Comment: De-install the 2 printer definitions on the MacBook, then turn everything off - printer, MacBook, router, WAP, other wifi-enabled devices (phones/tablets/computers). Restart the router & WAP. Wait a bit for router & WAP to configure themselves. Power up the printer. Power up the laptop and re-create the printer definition. You may also want to do  a semi-full or full reset of the printer itself: http://resetprinters.com/3-different-ways-to-reset-the-hp-officejet-6500-all-in-one-printer/

Comment: I've probably already deleted the printer but I'll give it another shot. Unlikely to perform a printer reset though as the touchscreen has become unresponsive, so I might be stuck during the config restore.

Comment: If the touchscreen on the printer has become unresponsive, then perhaps that's why the printer has become unresponsive?

Comment: IconDeamon printer works fine from Ubuntu and Win10, so I'd lean more towards a MBP issue. Touchscreen has become progressively unresponsive, with parts that would still respond, then become inop.

Comment: You write: "... both using wired connection ..." which I interpret to mean that Win10 and Ubuntu run on different CPU(s) than the MBP. From your description of the myriad problems, and the touchscreen going in-op, I'd say the printer is on its way out. Having serviced many laser & ink-jet printers from many manufacturers, I've found that at some point they need to be retired even if some (or most) of the functions are working. When the time comes, _recycle responsibly!_

Comment: Admittedly, it is suspicious, and yes, the printer is aged. But it still performs flawlessly (touchscreen aside) from 2 machines and not from the last one, so I'd be inclined to believe something is "wrong" between the MacBook Pro and the printer. So the question would be: how do I investigate further, as opposed to guessing or assuming? Hey, maybe I could bring it to the office and perform some tests on a different environment for instance. That would be one way. Here I was hoping for diagnosis actions or commands beyond `curl` and `ifconfig`...